# converting ß.cfg to upper case using toUpperCase() in java

Tags: java

I am trying following code

```
String s1 = "ß.cfg";
System.out.println (s.toUpperCase());
```

output I am getting is `SS.CFG` since Unicode didn't define an uppercase version of ß while I want the output as `ß.CFG`.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: Since 2008, there is an uppercase version: `ẞ` (U+1E9E), but the standard `toUpperCase` algorithm still maps `ß` to `SS` in 2018.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`toUpperCase( Locale )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28java.util.Locale%29) explicitly states that this is what will happen:

> Since case mappings are not always 1:1 char mappings, the resulting String may be a different length than the original String.
>
> small letter sharp s -> two letters: SS

Comment: is there any way i can achieve what i am trying to do?

Comment: I think you would need to write your own implementation of `toUppercase` so that it gets this letter wrong.  Maybe scan for `ß`, replace it, then delegate to the existing method... The Java implementation is the correct way to get uppercase `ß`

Comment: No it's not the correct way... anymore. Or it depends on your definition of correct. German had no ẞ in the past, so turning ß to SS was correct but now the German Language haves an upper case ß which is ẞ. I see why the java implementation can't be changed for compatibility but it's not what I would call correct.

Answer (score 6):

"ß" character is equivalent to "ss" (used in German, for example), and this is defined so in your Locale (the Locale you are using in your app).

You can try to do some experiment with a different Locale using method:

```
toUpperCase(Locale locale)
```

Edit: As the user said, this method is not valid, a possible workaroud (not very elegant) is:

```
    String s1 = new String ("auß.cfg").replace('ß', '\u9999');
    System.out.println (s1.toUpperCase(Locale.UK).replace('\u9999', 'ß'));
```

Comment: even passing locale results are same no change in output at all

Comment: You are right, the first 255 characters in unicode are translated with latin1 (class Character):

        if (codePoint <= FAST_PATH_MAX) { // FAST_PATH_MAX = 255
            upperCase = CharacterDataLatin1.toUpperCaseEx(codePoint);
        } else {
...

Comment: I would use `'ẞ'` directly, instead of `'\u9999'', and no need for the last replace....

Answer (score 4):

The Java implementation is simply following what the Unicode specification says.  And Unicode says this:

```
# ================================================================================
# Unconditional mappings
# ================================================================================

# The German es-zed is special--the normal mapping is to SS.
# Note: the titlecase should never occur in practice. It is equal to titlecase(uppercase(<es-zed>))

00DF; 00DF; 0053 0073; 0053 0053; # LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S
```

Reference: http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/SpecialCasing.txt

If you want to implement a form of uppercase conversion that is different to Unicode, you'll need to specify and implement it yourself.

---

<sub>(If you want to see a bunch of people getting hot under the collar about "uppercase ß", read this email thread - http://unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2007-m05/0007.html )</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Try [`java.lang.String.toUpperCase(java.util.Locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28java.util.Locale%29).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Characeter.toUpperCase()` ignores these rules, so that you can use it to implement the desired conversion:

> String case mapping methods have several benefits over Character case mapping methods. String case mapping methods can perform locale-sensitive mappings, context-sensitive mappings, and 1:M character mappings, whereas the Character case mapping methods cannot.

Answer (score 0):

> this will solve the case

```
char[] chars = "ßdenrä".toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[i]);
}
String output = new String(chars);
System.out.println(output);
```

> result: ßDENRÄ

Answer (score 0):

If you have mixed occurence of "ß" and "SS" in the origin word, then such simple method would help:

```
    private String toUppercaseWithSharpS(String originString) {
    Pattern sharpSPattern = Pattern.compile("ß");
    Matcher shaprSMatcher = sharpSPattern.matcher(originString);
    String placeholder = "SHARP-S";
    String upperCasedString = shaprSMatcher.replaceAll(placeholder);
    upperCasedString = upperCasedString.toUpperCase(); //replaces ß with SS, see https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8186073);
    upperCasedString = upperCasedString.replaceAll(placeholder, "ß");

    return upperCasedString;
}
```

Comment: why not just `originString.replace("ß", "ẞ").toUpperCase()`  (at least it will not fail if the original text contains `SHARP-S`, and slightly simpler) BTW no need to use regular expression to just replace plain text

Comment: or  `... .replace('ß', 'ẞ').toUpperCase()`

Comment: yes of course that works, however in my case there was weird goal to have in the output all letters with uppercase, but with small ß.
Desired (though weird):            `PARISER STRAßE`
Your proposal would produce: `PARISER STRAẞE`